# How can I write the body of an email in a separate function?

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I have the following macro that works great (found the code online):

```
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email()

Dim objOutl
Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objMailItem.Display
strEmailAddr = "User@Use.com"
objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddr
objMailItem.Subject = "Sample"    
objMailItem.Body = "Please come by when you get this." & vbNewLine _
                & " " & vbNewLine _
                & "Sample of Line 3"

objMailItem.Send
Set objMailItem = Nothing
Set objOutl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there a way to have the body written by executing a separate macro?  The end user has a fairly long email that is mostly standard so I wanted the body of the email be a separate macro if possible.

That way I can write as many custom messages as I want and each time the macro goes to write the body of the email I call a different macro that has the content that I want.

Comment: `objMailItem.Body = SomeOtherFunction`?

Comment: I tried objMailItem.Body = Call Macro1, the code that I used for Macro1 was objMailItem.Body = "Test", this did not work out.

Comment: Use a function that returns a `String`, not a `Sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email()

    Dim objOutl

    Set objOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMailItem = objOutl.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    objMailItem.Display
    strEmailAddr = "User@Use.com"
    objMailItem.Recipients.Add strEmailAddr
    objMailItem.Subject = "Sample"    
    objMailItem.Body = GetMessageBody()  ' <--- This line is different
    objMailItem.Send
    Set objMailItem = Nothing
    Set objOutl = Nothing

End Sub

' This Function has been added.
Private Function GetMessageBody() As String
    GetMessageBody = "Test."
End Function
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)